# C# Reflection : how to get an array values & length?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(MyDictionary).GetFields();
```

`MyDictionary` is a static class, all fields are string arrays.

How to get get the Length value of each array and then itearate through all elements ?
I tried the cast like:

```
field as Array
```

but it causes an error

> Cannot convert type 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo' to 'System.Array'
>   via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion,
>   wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I need to iterate through all array's elements to check if some values exists in any array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit after your edit**: Note that what you have is reflection objects, not objects or values related to your own class. In other words, those `FieldInfo` objects you have there are common to all instances of your class. The only way to get to the string arrays is to use those `FieldInfo` objects to get to the field value of a particular instance of your class.

For that, you use [FieldInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx). It returns the value of the field as an object.

Since you already know they are string arrays, that simplifies things:

If the fields are static, pass `null` for the `obj` parameter below.

```
foreach (var fi in fields)
{
    string[] arr = (string[])fi.GetValue(obj);
    ... process array as normal here
}
```

If you want to ensure you only process fields with string arrays:

```
foreach (var fi in fields)
{
    if (fi.FieldType == typeof(string[]))
    {
        string[] arr = (string[])fi.GetValue(obj);
        ... process array as normal here
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but in this case I pressume the 'obj' would be an instance of the MyDictionary class, but I can't make an instance of that class because it's a static class

Comment: Just pass null for obj, I didn't read your question thoroughly enough :)

Comment: @Tony just pass null instead of obj

Answer (score 14):

As an example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class MyDictionary
    {
        public static int[] intArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
        public static string[] stringArray = new string[] { "zero", "one", "two" };
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(MyDictionary).GetFields();

            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                if (field.FieldType.IsArray)
                {
                    Array array = field.GetValue(null) as Array;

                    Console.WriteLine("Type: " + array.GetType().GetElementType().ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Length: " + array.Length.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Values");
                    Console.WriteLine("------");

                    foreach (var element in array)
                        Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.Readline();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(MyDictionary).GetFields();
foreach (FieldInfo info in fields) {
  string[] item = (string[])info.GetValue(null);
  Console.WriteLine("Array contains {0} items:", item.Length);
  foreach (string s in item) {
    Console.WriteLine("  " + s);
  }
}
```