# Determine if an object is an array of any type, and access the array length

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have an overridden method that has an `object` parameter. I am determining if this is an array, and then want to determine its length:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    if (type.IsArray)
    {
        return ((object[]) value).Length > 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is if `value` is an `int[]`, it errors when I try to cast to an `object[]`. Is there any way to handle this cast so it will work with any type of array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Reflection : how to get an array values & length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194287/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-an-array-values-length)

Comment: Be careful using the term "generic" as it's means something specific in C#, though you can do this in a [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) way.

Comment: You need to make a new array. Value type arrays can't be cast to `object[]`, because all the values need to be boxed. All that aside, what you're doing seems like a code smell; are you sure you can't just accept an `Array` as the parameter?

Comment: Are you able to modify the method you are overriding or are you stuck with this method signature?

Comment: Not all you code paths return a value. What do you return if `value` is not an array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cast `value` to the base `System.Array` class:

```
return ((Array) value).Length > 0
```

By using the `as` operator, you can simplify your code further:

```
public static bool IsValid(object value)
{
    Array array = value as Array;
    return array != null && array.Length > 0;
}
```

**Note:** This will return `true` for multidimensional arrays such as `new int[10, 10]`. If you want to return `false` in this case, add a check for `array.Rank == 1`.

Comment: Using `as` you should at least check for `array == null`.

Comment: @MattBurland: Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that avoids having to interrogate the type in your validation method is to use dynamic dispatch:

```
// Default overload
public static bool IsValid(object value) 
{ return false; }

// If it's an array
public static bool IsValid(Array value)
{
    return value.Length > 0;
}

...

bool isValid = IsValid((dynamic)obj); // Will call the overload corresponding to type of obj
```