# Getting class attributes length

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

In the first time I'm going to introduce you what I need to do, because I think this is not a "normal" problem, but quite a specific one.

I have a class `Words`, which defines 16 bools.
This class is used in my generic `OldParser` class because it's defined every single attributes. Here is one of my class looks like with Words type attributes.

```
class MyClass: OldParser 
{
    public Words[] arg1 = new Words[2]; 
    public Words[] arg2 = new Words[5];
    public Words arg3;
}
```

Then I have an array of Words, which contains what I need to create my class.
So the first two Words will go to arg1. The 5 others to arg2 and the last one to arg3.
And of course, I need it to be generic for every class I have, so it needs to be generic.

So here is my question: How can I be able to get the List of all the attribute of my class? And then how to know the size of the array?

For example, for this class, I need to get every attributes and to know that my first attribute is an array of 2, my second an array of 5 and my last attributes isn't an array.

I used:

```
List<System.Reflection.FieldInfo> list = typeof(MyClass)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public)
            .ToList();
```

In order to get my class attributes. But I don't know how to get the size of the arrays and also, I'm not sure that I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I am kinda disturbed by the usage of the term *Attribute*, which is more connected to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx - do you mean flags? ... please elaborate!

Comment: I'm confused by what these words are. You say "the first two Words will go to arg1" but I'm unclear on where these words are coming from? Are you just getting a list of 6 words passed into a constructor for this object or something?

Comment: @dotctor I am troubled with your edit, as it is primarily based on assumptions. The question and wording itself is unclear, so you should rather let the OP do his/her job!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Reflection : how to get an array values & length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194287/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-an-array-values-length)

Comment: By attribute, i mean for example "public Words[] arg1 = new Words[2];".

And i just want to be able, for all my attributes (in a foreach), to check their size and to set them a value. This value is coming from a Word Array.

Comment: @ReCoF you should try to follow the well-established namings within the scope of the .NET framework and not call them *Attributes* then ;)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair What is it ? Attributes is actually how we call it in my country, so i though it was the same thing. I'm sorry then.

Comment: @ReCoF You see - there are differences between technical and natural names/terms. I just wanted to remind you of that, and that (at least for me) it might be confusing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like,

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
var fieldInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetFields();

var myArraysAndLengths = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var field in fieldInfos)
{
    var fieldName = field.Name;
    var fieldValue = field.GetValue(myClass);
    var fieldType = field.FieldType;
    if (fieldType == typeof (Words[]))
    {
        var value = (Words[]) fieldValue;
        var length = value.Length;
        myArraysAndLengths[fieldName] = length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the fields are non-static you cannot access array lengths without having an instance. After creating an instance you can do something like this:

```
MyClass instance = ...;

IDictionary<FieldInfo, int> arrayLengths = list.Where(field => field.FieldType.IsArray)
    .ToDictionary(field => field, 
                  field => ((Array)field.GetValue(instance)).Length);
```