# How do you extract an array from a System.Object value?

Tags: c#, types

Using a bit of reflection, I'm getting values from properties and fields of arbitrary objects. Because the value can be of any type, both FieldInfo.GetValue() and PropertyInfo.GetValue() return an instance of System.Object which you are then tasked with deducing what it is.

My problem comes from values that are of array types (e.g. int[]). I intend to extract the values from the array however I don't know how and all attempts of finding a solution online have failed me. As you can see in the example below, I can both identify that the object is indeed an array and determine its element type, but beyond that I have no clue how to proceed.

```
static void DoThingWithArray(this object value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    if (type.IsArray)
    {
        Type elementType = type.GetElementType();
        //Extract array elements and length
    }
}
```

Comment: Cast `value` to `IEnumerable` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Reflection : how to get an array values & length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194287/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-an-array-values-length)

Comment: You can cast to `Array`, and then use `GetValue` to get specific elements

Comment: @RandRandom Thanks for the suggestion, it partially worked but was unclear how to get the values. Canton's method worked so I just used that.

Comment: FYI to whoever wanted to close this, similar questions to this didn't address what you do when you don't know what you're casting to which was my problem. I believe this question deserves to stick around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that an array implements the non-generic `IList` interface in the `System.Collections` namespace:

```
static void DoThingWithArray(this object value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    if (type.IsArray)
    {
        IList array = (IList)value;
    }
}
```

Now you can extract values by index, loop over it etc etc.